# Way to access Samsung Galaxy S4 as USB device without Rooting the phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, data-recovery, usb-connection-mode

How I can connect my Samsung Galaxy S4 to my PC as a USB device.

I tried the [Build Number](http://www.device-recovery.com/how-to-connect-android-devices-to-pc-with-usb-mass-storage-mode) shortcut and it did not work. Enabling USB debugging does not fix the problem. The reason behind this is to recover some deleted videos and all the apps require the phone to be connect as a USB device.

Comment: Do you mean specifically a *USB mass storage* device, not just a USB device?

Comment: As Dan suggests: the context of "recover some deleted X" makes it very likely you're specifically looking for UMS, as that would give the recovery software "full access to the drive". Can you confirm that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Samsung Kies on the computer. That will install the appropriate driver; at that point your phone when connected should appear in My Computer (assuming we're talking about Windows 7/8/8.1). If you're running OS X you'll need to install the Android Transfer utility from Samsung. Most Android phones use a generic Google-provided MTP driver, but Samsung rolled their own and the generic one doesn't work.

It's a hassle to install Kies, but Samsung does not provide a stand-alone installer for their MTP driver. Once installed, you can ignore it. The phone will appear in My Computer and be browsable from Windows Explorer.